# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeError' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I am submitting the form. My number field is unique. Then this problem occurs.

```
$('#' + first_item).parsley().removeError('required', {
  updateClass: true
});
$('#' + first_item).parsley().addError('required', {
     message: value,
     updateClass: true
});
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Have you provided the data-parsley-validate="true" details on the form tag. Do share your form html which would help further to investigate.